# Not duplicating the data into a table when it's inserted

Tags: c#, mysql

i made a register algorithm in C#. There's two textboxes (user, password) and 1 button (register). On register's button event there's a method that insert's the textbox.texts into the Database in Users Table .
How can i make not to insert the same user in the table?
For exemple : Throw an error message " The username is already taken "

Thanks !
This is the method that i was talking about:

```
      public void InsertUser(string UserID,string UserPas)
          {

         string query = "INSERT INTO TabelaUtilizatori (name, password)VALUES('"+UserID+"', '"+UserPas+"')";

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use trigger in database. Triggers check username before insert an when find this do not allow insert to database.

Comment: And how can i see if there's(in table) already a user with that username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string insertString = "INSERT INTO TabelaUtilizatori (name, password) VALUES('"+UserID+"', '"+UserPas+"')";
        string selectString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TabelaUtilizatori where name=" + "'" + UserID + "'";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectString, connection);
            int Result = 0;
            Result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (Result == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username Already Exists");
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            else{
              MySqlCommand cmdInsert = new MySqlCommand(insertString, connection);
            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
            MessageBox.Show("Inregistration Sucessful");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant, but if it performs OK for you, there's nothing wrong with running a simple `SELECT` query like this first:

```
SELECT * FROM TabelaUtilizatori WHERE name='" + UserID + "'";
```

If the `SELECT` has no results, the username is free.  If the result contains a row, the username already exists.

Alternately, if the username is the primary key of your TableaUtilizatori table, then attempts to insert the same username a second time will result in an error that you can catch and report.

One other side thought:  storing passwords as plain text is generally a bad idea.  At the minimum you should probably store a hash of the password.  An even better solution would be to hash and salt it.  That way if you database is compromised, usernames and passwords aren't sitting there in plain text.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i would like to vote your answer, but i don't have enough reputation!

Comment: No problem!  If you think this was the correct answer, you should accept it so people who visit the site in the future know (you can always accept even if you can't upvote).